# Shell script issue: cron job script to Restart MySQL server when it stops accidentally

Tags: bash, mysql, cron, scripts

I have this script, I am using it to setup CRON job to execute this script, so it can check if MySQL service is running; if not then it restart the MySQL service:

```
#!/bin/bash
service mysql status| grep 'mysql start/running' > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    sudo service mysql restart
fi
```

I have setup cron job as.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then added,

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ubuntu/mysql-check.sh
```

Problem is that it restart MySQL on every cron job execution.. 
even if server is running it restart the MySQL service
what is correction in the script to do that.

Comment: why do you have a `\\` in front of your shebang?  If it's there to keep it from looking like a comment, then it's unnecessary.  [Shebangs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) are treated special like by Bash, as in they don't need to be escaped because they aren't comments in the sense that a comment is a piece of code that is _not_ evaluated _at all_.

Comment: Also, avoid using `[ ... ]` or `test <TEST>` in Bash.  They're [deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).  Use `[[ ... ]]` instead.  Only use `[ ... ]` and/or `test <TEST>` when `[[ ... ]]` is __not__ available.

Comment: this is first shell script I tried by using some available scripts, I just modified it. don't know much about syntax. problem is still there mysql restarts on every CRON job execution @AlexejMagura

Comment: Try something like this: `if ! (service mysql status | grep 'mysql start/running' &>/dev/null); then sudo service mysql restart; fi`  What this does, is it starts up a subshell, wherein `service mysql status | grep 'mysql start/running' &> /dev/null` gets run, the return (exit) status of said subshell then gets passed to the if-statement, which then checks to see if it is non-zero, and if it is _not_ non-zero then it runs the `then` block.

Comment: Doesn't mysql write its process pid to pid file? If it does you could use that as another way to check your mysql status

Comment: Quite a long time ago, MySQL installation came with the default script called `safe_mysqld` or something like this (I don't remember details anymore) that was used to start the service. This script itself was monitoring the service and restarting it if it happens to crash. Is it no more the case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suspect that you setup the cron job to execute this script in your crontab file, and not in the root crontab file. This is not correct because if you *don't* run `service mysql status` as root, the `mysql` service will not be recognized.

So, modify the script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
then
    /usr/sbin/service mysql start
fi
```

Be sure that is executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

Then add a new entry in the root crontab as follow:

- Edit root crontab file using:

  ```
  sudo crontab -e
  ```
- And add the following line to the file:

  ```
  */1 * * * * /path/to/script
  ```
- Note: I have set the cron job for every minute, but you can change as you wish or as you think is better. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron in this sense.

Comment: I setup it as crontab, I guess problem is with the script, i'll try above script

Comment: `./mysql-check.sh: line 2: [: =~: binary operator expected` error in above script

Comment: I believe you want to negate that regex matching with `!` if you actually intend to restart the mysql service on crash

Comment: @Flint That's true also... Sorry, I'm still drinking my morning coffee. :)

Comment: @D_Vaibhavツ Now should be everything OK. So, try now, as root.

Comment: I have added crontab as `*/1 * * * * /home/ubuntu/mysql-check.sh`

Comment: I had to add @donkzilla PATH value to my crontab in order for it to work.

Comment: I added `echo "MySQL restarted" | mail -s "vvaaccc.com MySQL" testtt@gmail.com` to get notified each time restart the mysql, each time I run the bash file it is sending the mail, so I feel if condition is not checking well where there mysql is running or not, so it is restarting the service each time.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
TMP=`mysqladmin -u root -pPassword status 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -f1 -d:`
case ${TMP} in
Uptime)
        echo "MySQL is running."
        echo "You are good"
;;
*)
        service mysql restart
        # the following sends an email for notification, change email address if needed.
        echo "MySQL restarted" | mail -s "your-site-name.com MySQL" email@gmail.com
;;
esac

Comment: I had to change `"start/running"` to `"active (running)"` and then it worked

Answer (score 3):

Radu's answer nearly worked. I had to set the path to make it work:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
if [[ ! "$(service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
then
    service mysql start
fi
```

Comment: In fact I have set my `PATH` in the crontab file. Anyway, in your case you need to use `PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH` or use the full path for `service` as I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Radu's answer works - but this script works as well

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(pgrep mysql | wc -l) = 0 ]];
then
    sudo service mysql start;
fi
```

Comment: I checked the `pgrep mysql` and I got `0` for mysql being stopped and `2` for running. Therefor I set the condition as`if [[ $(pgrep mysql | wc -l) = 0 ]];` and it worked for me.

Comment: probably better your way... I'll make the change.

Comment: This script works with `/bin/bash`(it does not work without bash).
`*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /root/mysql-check.sh`

Answer (score 2):

#### Restart

With systemd you can set up your service to [`Restart`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) on certain conditions:

```sh
systemctl cat mysql.service | grep Restart     # Check current status. cat PATTERN... Show files and drop-ins of specified units
```

Probably you wish to move from `on-abort` to `on-failure`, on `[Service]` section.

```sh
sudo EDITOR=nano systemctl edit mysql.service
```

- `nano` or [whatever editor you want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408414/209677).
- To do this temporary use `--runtime`, changes will be lost on next reboot.
- Add a [`RestartSec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=) to sleep before restarting a service.

Other useful commands:

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload  # Reload systemd manager configuration. `systemctl edit` automatically does this for you.
systemctl cat mysql.service   # unit configuration
systemd-delta                 # Check the whole system changes
```

#### OOMScoreAdjust

On the same place, you may also want to adjust systemd [OOMScoreAdjust](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=):

> Sets the adjustment value for the Linux kernel's Out-Of-Memory (OOM) killer score for executed processes. Takes an integer between -1000 (to disable OOM killing of processes of this unit) and 1000 (to make killing of processes of this unit under memory pressure very likely).

```ini
# Useful options not previously available in [mysqld_safe]

# Kernels like killing mysqld when out of memory because its big.
# Lets temper that preference a little.
# OOMScoreAdjust=-600
```

Read also [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/349837).

---

You can also reduce the memory usage of MySQL/MariaDB by tuning some options like `max_connections`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` (probably on `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`).